# PackageManagement Cmdlets are not recognized by powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

Hi there i have a problem on a windows server 2016. I can't install any packages with the PackageManagement Cmdlets. Im always getting the error that it's not recognized as a cmdlet or function if i use them.

i tired importing the module which works. But i still cant use any command. The Error is in german and im not sure it will help you that much.

This happens when i try to install a module :

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> install-module powershellget
PackageManagement\Get-PackageProvider : Die Benennung "PackageManagement\Get-PackageProvider" wurde nicht als Name
eines Cmdlet, einer Funktion, einer Skriptdatei oder eines ausführbaren Programms erkannt. Überprüfen Sie die
Schreibweise des Namens, oder ob der Pfad korrekt ist (sofern enthalten), und wiederholen Sie den Vorgang.
In C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:7277 Zeichen:26
+ ...        $nugetProvider = PackageManagement\Get-PackageProvider -ErrorA ...
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (PackageManagement\Get-PackageProvider:String) [], CommandNotFoundExcept
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PackageManagement\Get-PackageProvider : Die Benennung "PackageManagement\Get-PackageProvider" wurde nicht als Name
eines Cmdlet, einer Funktion, einer Skriptdatei oder eines ausführbaren Programms erkannt. Überprüfen Sie die
Schreibweise des Namens, oder ob der Pfad korrekt ist (sofern enthalten), und wiederholen Sie den Vorgang.
In C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:7291 Zeichen:40
+ ... ailableNugetProviders = PackageManagement\Get-PackageProvider -Name $ ...
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (PackageManagement\Get-PackageProvider:String) [], CommandNotFoundExcept
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Is [PackageManagement module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PackageManagement/1.3.1) installed? Did you Import the module in your code? I don't see any of your code or error messages in your question.. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i tired importing the module which works. But i still cant use any command. The Error is in german and im not sure it will help you that much.

Comment: You are creating a very strange command there as if it were a file path.. After Importing the PackageManagement module, use the function as `$nugetProvider = Get-PackageProvider`. See the examples in [Get-PackageProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/packagemanagement/get-packageprovider?view=powershell-6)

Comment: i can't. It does say that "Get-PackageProvider" is not being recognized as a cmdlet function or script.

Comment: The minimum PowerShell version for the  PackageManagement  module is 3.0. Do you have that or better? Did you do a `Install-Module -Name PackageManagement`

Comment: @Theo Server2016 ships with PSv5.1

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Aha, then I'm out of ideas here.. Bailing out.

Comment: Okay guys i got it. Idid `install-module packagemanagement` and installed a newer version, my old version was 1.0.0.0 . Now everything seem to work properly.